# JMS Serializer DateTime not deserializing?

Tags: symfony, datetime, serialization, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have a sort of special setup of Symfony2, FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle, due to a legacy DB in the background. I'm struggling to get a PUT request working, including the deserialization of a DateTime property.

First things first. This is a model snippet, notice the `DateTime` format:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sys_lastmodifieddate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'>")
 *
 * @Expose
 */
private $sysLastmodifieddate;
```

I have built a `Form\Type` to support persisting incoming entities:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('officialname')
        ->add('shortname')
        ->add('shortinfo')
        ->add('web')      
        ->add('fk_clientsector')      
        ->add($builder->create('sys_lastmodifieddate')->addViewTransformer(new DateTimeToStringTransformer()));
}
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
public function putClientAction(Request $request, $id )
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Client')->find($id);

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new \AcmeBundle\ClientType(), $entity);
    $form->submit($request);

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($this->view(null, Codes::HTTP_OK));

}
```

Now, my problem is that updates to any field coming in via JSON will get executed, but the `DateTime` field.

Example request, submitted via a PUT route:

```
{
    "shortname":"some client",
    "officialname":"some client",
    "sys_lastmodifieddate":"2016-06-13T11:20:49+01:00",
    "fk_clientsector":"5"
}
```

Resulting update statement from the log:

```
UPDATE crm_client SET shortname = ?, officialname = ?, fk_clientsector = ? WHERE id = ? ["some client", "some client", "5", 12345]
```

No sign of the date anywhere. Got any hints why this is happening, what I'm doing wrong? Will be happy to provide any requested info.

Note: I have already tried naming the Model property `$sys_lastmodifieddate` (lowercase and underscored), but that breaks the form altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend to use the DateTime ParamConverter by Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#datetime-converter If required you can easily extend it or write your own custom ParamConverter.

Comment: To be honest, I already gave the FOSRestBundle's Request Body Converter a go (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html), but I'm not quite sure how to populate the resulting entity without doing `$em->...find($id)` and assigning each property separately?

Comment: I will post a new question if that's the way to go!