# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle form submission on PUT action with Request Body Listener

Tags: forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

Referencing this question: [JMS Serializer DateTime not deserializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788608/jms-serializer-datetime-not-deserializing), I have narrowed this down to the folowing:

I have got a controller with a put action using a Request Body Listener:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("client", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */
public function putClientAction($id, Client $client)
{
    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $logger->info(serialize((array) $client));
    $logger->info("ID: " . $id);


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('SomeBundle:Client')->find($id);


    $logger->info(serialize($entity));

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new \SomeBundle\Form\ClientType(), $entity);
    $form->submit((array) $client, false);

    $logger->info(serialize($entity));

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($this->view(null, Codes::HTTP_OK));
}
```

My question concerns the `$form->submit()` call, or rather, how would I go about and actually submit the incoming `$client` entity? I have tried submitting the object, or an (array) representation of it, with the `$clearmissing` flag set to `false` to avoid `null` values being passed in, but an `UPDATE` never happens.

To be sure, the logged entity representations look fine, it's just that `$entity` never gets filled with `$client`s values.

Got any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

#### Edit

This is what a PUT request looks like:

```
{
  "shortname":"...",
  "officialname":"...",
  "shortinfo":"..." 
  ...
}
```

#### Edit 2

I've narrowed it down (again) to a problem with the `DateTime` data type:

```
...
$logger->info("REQUEST" . print_r($request->request->all(), true));
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new Type(), $entity);
$form->submit($request, false);

$logger->info($form->getData()->getUpdatedAt()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'));
```

The `$request` object contains an updated DateTime, but it is never passed to the form (the second log shows the original date). The form `Type`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('updatedAt', 'datetime', array('format' => 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'))
}
```

I guess this is a problem with Symfony Forms and DateTime objects, then?

Comment: I have tried another datetime format on in the form Type : `->add('updatedAt', 'datetime', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'html5' => false, 'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"))` as per http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax ... however, to no avail

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you submit your data. You should use less complex way.

Here is example:

```
public function putPostAction(Post $post, Request $request)
{
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form   = $this->createForm('content_post',$post);

    $form->submit($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();

        return $post;
    }

    return $form;
}
```

You don't need to query client in your code because controller will automatically convert it for you.

Also you should use Request object, it will contain all data that you've submitted.

$form->submit($request) has a key part here.

$form will return all your validations errors.

My FOSRestConfig

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

Comment: I should maybe mention... I'm using an Ember frontend for this project... the ID is nowhere present in the payload. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Depends on your form name. If your form name like content_post you should send request with this form name like [content_post]title. In other case your form won't be valid.

Comment: I updated the question w/ a sample PUT request in JSON format. Do you mean I have to wrap it in a e.g. 'client' element? Even though I created it with an empty name (`->createNamed('', new \SomeBundle\Form\ClientType()`) ?

Comment: No, with ->createNamed you don't need to wrap it. With your json input it works either.